# ViewDidLoad() not triggering background refresh

Tags: ios, swift3, singleton, viewcontroller, viewdidload

So The community has been a great helping me along with a school project. However I've hit a snag. I'm building a simple Kitchen timer app thats a SVC with a tab view. The first page allows the user to set the timer, then the second is a basic settings page that allows the user to trigger a random background color I made to fulfill the requirements of the assignment. Everything is working great say for one part. Once the user triggers a random color to be used as a background, I wanted that background color to also be applied to the other views. I went with the advice I sought out here: [Change viewController BG color based off another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448525/change-viewcontroller-bg-color-based-off-another-view-controller?noredirect=1#comment75925950_44448525) and used singleton. However when I navigate from the settings view, to the timer view nothing happens. Now I added `self.view.backgroundColor = Settings.sharedInstance.backgroundColor` to my `viewDidLoad()` like so:

```
`override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.backgroundColor = Settings.sharedInstance.backgroundColor
    print(Settings.sharedInstance.backgroundColor)
}
```

`
Nothing seems to happen. However! as a test, I added the same block to :

```
@IBAction func pickerStartButtonChnage(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.view.backgroundColor = Settings.sharedInstance.backgroundColor
    print(Settings.sharedInstance.backgroundColor)

    if !cron.isValid{ // prevent more than one time on the thread
        nameIt.text = cronStr(cronCount)
        cron = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval,
                               target: self,
                               selector: #selector(TimerViewController.timerDidEnd(_:)),
                               userInfo: "is done!",
                               repeats: true) //repeating timer in the second iteration
    }
}
```

It works!
My question is why is the background not being triggered in the `viewDidLoad()`, when it works fine when the button is triggered? I appreciate any advice in advance, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the color in `viewWillAppear()` instead. `viewDidLoad()` happens when the view is first loaded into memory, but `viewWillAppear()` gets called every time it will appear.

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    self.view.backgroundColor = Settings.sharedInstance.backgroundColor
}
```